# How to create little colored shape in a cell that would indicate colors on a chart? SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a bar chart with different bar colors. Below in a table I just want to indicate what each color means.

Can I do something like that in SSRS?

[image]

Im sure I can create another column on a left and assign each color to a cell. But is any way I can display it the way its on a picture above?

I tried to use indicators for that but I guess it needs conditions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what tool was used to build the report you are trying to mimic above?

Comment: just add a rectangle and set it's colour

Comment: the tool I am trying to mimic is simple Excel.

Comment: I tried with rectangle, but when I drop it to a cell - it gives a color to the whole cell. But you are right, maybe I shouldnt drop to a cell and simply place it next to it.

Comment: Creating images with a white or transparent border would be another option. Especially if you know which colors you'll be using ahead of time.

Comment: Put a rectangle in the table cell. Then put a text box in the rectangle for the color and another textbox for the text. You can resize the color text box so it's thinner than the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with custom code.

Loose steps to follow are:

- Create a list to hold the graph
- Add the graph
- Inside the list and below the graph, add a tablix
- The tablix will row group on the same thing as the graph (so you can get a row per coloured item in the graph)
- Add a column to the start of the tablix for the colour
- Add the following custom code:

`Private colourPalette As String() = {"#418CF0", "#FCB441", "#DF3A02", "#056492", "#BFBFBF", "#1A3B69", "#FFE382", "#129CDD", "#CA6B4B", "#005CDB", "#F3D288", "#506381", "#F1B9A8", "#E0830A", "#7893BE"}`

`Private count As Integer = 0`

`Private mapping As New System.Collections.Hashtable()`

```
Public Function GetColour(ByVal groupingValue As String) As String
    If mapping.ContainsKey(groupingValue) Then
                Return mapping(groupingValue)
    End If
    Dim c As String = colourPalette(count Mod colourPalette.Length)
    count = count + 1
    mapping.Add(groupingValue, c)
    Return c
End Function
```

- For the series fill on the graph, use the follow expression:
  [image: Code]
- Use the same expression for the fill on the initial column in the tablix

You can use any list of codes for colour - this is the list for the default palette in SSRS.
This code ensures the same colour is picked each time the same item is used - so in the image the same colour is returned each time the same Category is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use is pretty simple.

I use Windows Character Map to find a character I like. For example: ■

Copy that character and add an expression where you want to show the color icon. Your expression text will be

="■"

Then go to the Font tab and Color. Select the color you want from the menu. You can use expression logic in here to change the color dynamically. (You can refer to other answer for details there)